# is it true that surjective chain map induce surjective homomorphism between homology groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Need surjective chain map induce surjective homomorphism between homology groups?
Since $f_*[x]\to[f(x)]$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, consider the morphism of chain complexes of vector spaces over a field $k$ $$C:= ... \to 0\to k \to k \to 0\to ...$$ and  $$C':= ... \to 0 \to k \to 0 \to 0\to ...$$ where the first $k$ is in degree $0$ for both complexes, and consider $f: C \to C'$ as the obvious non zero morphism between those two ($id$ in degree $0$ and $0$ otherwise). Then this defines a surjective morphism of chain complexes, but since $H^*(C)=0$ and $H^0(C')=k$ we get that $H^*(f)$ can't be surjective.

The problem with your reasoning is that your preimage might die in homology, i.e not even be represented.

Comment: vvery thankful!

Comment: Is this example really correct?
What is the operator $\partial:k\to k$?
1) If it is $Id$ the identity, then $f\partial =Id$ while $\partial f = 0$ and then $f$ is not a chain map.
2) If it is $0$, then $H^0(C)$ is also $k$, instead of $0$.

Comment: It is the identity, and $f$ is going from $C$ to $C'$ so both $f \circ d =0 =d \circ f$ just for degree reasons. I am quite sure you confused the direction of the arrow. Actually what is happening here is that no matter what you do, a square ending in $0$ always commutes.